# @Font-Face rendering in Chrome 40

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am running in to some very weird font renderings with Google Chrome 40, and am hoping that someone else has encountered and knows how to fix. Everything was working fine until two days ago, so I'm wondering if its simply a bug with the new chrome, but I can't locate any other cases of this.

This is happening with all three font-face embeds that I use on my site, one of which is google web fonts, the other two are locally embedded.

I tested with the following browsers: 
Chrome 38 (Mac) - OK
Chrome 40 (Mac) Canary - Bad 
Chrome 40 (Win) Canary - Inconsistent

Safari 7.1 - OK
Safari 8.0 - OK

Firefox 32.0.1 - OK
Firefox 33.0 Beta - OK
Firefox Aurora 34.0a2 - OK
Firefox Nightly 35.0a1 - OK

IE 11 - OK
IE 10 - OK

I have the following attached to the `body` element in my css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font: {
        family: $font-body;
        size: 1.4rem;
    }
    color: $midnight-blue;
    background-color: $white;
    line-height: $alt-baseline;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; 
}
```

Here is a screenshot with the problem:

Chrome 38 (OK): http://cl.ly/XwN8

Chrome 40 (Bad): http://cl.ly/XwqN

Comment: Real CSS code not shown. HTML not shown.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, even for built-in fonts (Helvetica, etc...) but haven't yet figured out why. The fonts render the same with `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` and without it, so it seems that property isn't taking effect.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Understood, however it would be impossible to show the HTML code for my entire site, which is what is affected. This is the SCSS code that is affecting all text, and this glitch applies to everything, including default body copy. What else should I include to give you more information?

Comment: @Runningskull After playing around with this more, I saw the same results on several other websites (not owned by me), however many other sites render fine. I'm going to try and dig into this a bit more and will report back.

Comment: Any news on this? I also see this on Mac & Chrome 40.

Comment: To be precise, it appears on Mac OS X 10.9.5 and Chrome 40.0.2214.10 beta (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was fixed in Chrome Canary 40.0.2197.2.

Comment: I can't comment if it was fixed in 40.0.2197.2 or not, but it's certainly broken as per the original report in 41.0.2216.0. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I went to chrome://flags/ and set "LCD text antialiasing" to Disabled.

Comment: there is no such thing `LCD text antialiasing` at chrome://flags/

Comment: Hmm. I'm Using Chrome Beta (Version 40.0.2214.10 beta (64-bit)). [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/UKj6O4U.png)